# Populate datatable with Set<RequestVO>

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

I'm calling this method:

```
public Set<RequestVO> getRequestBySupplier(SupplierVO objectVO)
```

I have a `OrderController` with this property and method, that is called on a button click:

```
public Set<RequestVO> requestList

public void listOrders()
{
     requestList = requestBO.getRequestBySupplier(supplierVO);
}
```

Debugging I can see that the `requestList` is been populated with the correct information.
On my `orderSearch.html` I have this datatable:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty orderController.requestList}">
     <h:dataTable value="#{orderController.requestList}" var="order">
          <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">#</f:facet>
               <h:outputText value="#{order.id}" escape="false" />
          </h:column>
     </h:dataTable>
</ui:fragment>
```

I have on my `orderController` the `requestList` get and set methods.

When I run the code I get this error:

> /views/fornecedor/orderSearch.xhtml @34,84 value="#{order.id}": The
>   class 'java.util.HashSet' does not have the property 'id'.

And the `Stack Trace`:

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:
>   /views/fornecedor/orderSearch.xhtml @34,84 value="#{order.id}": The
>   class 'java.util.HashSet' does not have the property 'id'.    at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)   at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.renderRow(TableRenderer.java:384)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeChildren(TableRenderer.java:161)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
>     at com.erp3.gui.filters.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`h:datatable` does not support `Set` , You can convert it to `List`

for example

```
public List <RequestVO> getListAsSet(Set<RequestVO> set) {
  return new ArrayList<RequestVO>(set);
}
```

b.t.w `ui:repeat` does not support `Set` too

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel following your solution I did this `requestList = new ArrayList<>(requestBO.getRequestBySupplier(supplierVO));` on my method and it worked. Thanks